# Почему все форки Telegram не работают без proxy/VPN?

Tags: android, telegram

Всем привет. Как Telegram сервер сообщает Android клиенту актуальный IP адрес для подключения? Как я понимаю код, за это отвечающий, не распространяется в открытом доступе, потому что если собрать Telegram из [исходников на Github](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram) приложение будет работать только с прокси или VPN, в то время как официальный клиент подключается без них. Наскольно наслышан, сервер шлет клиенту IP адрес как-то через Google. Если это так, то расскажите, кто знает, об этом поподробнее.

Так вот, что есть такого в официальном клиенте, чего нет на Github? Имеет ли смысл декомпилировать официальный клиент? Возможно ли повторить работоспособность в своем форке?

Comment: Как по мне закрытость этого инструмента очевидна. Если бы он был в открытом доступе и любой мог бы разобраться ка кон работает, то даже у ркн хватило бы ума эту систему сломать. Ну или заплатить тем, кто бы понял как эту систему сломать. Потому я бы рекомендовал даже не искать, не дай Форд найдете, а следом за вами ркн и у телеграма опять будут проблемы с доступностью. Или вы сами из ркн?)

Comment: @Спицко Дмитрий, следом за мной - никакого ркн не будет, так как если я и найду решение, я так же не буду выкладывать его в опенсорс. И нет, я не из ркн

Answer (score 3):

Ответ обновляемый.

Telegram шлет Android клиенту актуальный список IP адресов через Firebase Cloud Messaging.